# Strange NodeJS behavior on fs.readdir and empty directory

Tags: node.js, windows, readdir

I have code like this which checks for existence of directory before reading the directory:

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.exists(dir, function (exists) {
    if(exists) {
        fs.readdir(dir, function (err, files) {
            //handling error
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }

            resolve(files);
        });
    } else {
        reject("Does not exist");
    }
});
```

The exists boolean returns true, but the call to readdir returns errno -4058, no such file or directory.

This only happens on Windows, and only happens when there's no files in the directory.

If I add a file to the empty dir, the call to readdir is successful.

Any ideas?

Comment: I would need more code to help, where does resolve / reject comes from, what kind of string `dir` is

Comment: It could be related to access rights.